# How to extracts a links under multiple Span tags using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I need to count and display the number of links available under different Span Tags.
In the following HTML code, I have two anchor links under Span 'Upcoming Event' and 4 links under 'Recent Free LIVE Webinars' section.

Please provide an Xpath to get these details.

```
<!-- language: html -->

<div class="widget widget_text">
<div class="widget-wrap">
<div class="textwidget">
<span style="color: #FF3300;font-size:14px">
<b>Upcoming Event </b>
</span>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/events/mobile-application-testing-   
            career">2nd July 2013:Your Career in Mobile Application Testing </a>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/live-training/qtp-11-live-
            training#">19thJune 2013 : QTP Live Training</a>


    <span style="color: #FF3300;font-size:14px">
             <b>Recent Free LIVE Webinars</b>
             </span>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/events/teachitelenter code hereearn-a-
            mega-webinar">Teach@ITeLearn Initiative </a>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/events/how-to-be-a-software-security-
            testing-expert">How to become a Software Security Testing Expert?</a>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/events/how-to-master-hp-qtp">How to    
            Master QTP?</a>

    <a href="http://www.itelearn.com/events/how-to-master-selenium-video-
            page">How to Master Selenium?     
            </a>
```

Comment: Well, in what language?

Answer (score 1):

To me this would be the easiest method. Find all the `spans` on the page, then for each `span` find all of the `anchor` elements, print the length of that list and then iterate over the list to get the `href` value and print that too.

```
spans = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for span in spans:
    links = span.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    print(str(links.length()));
    for link in links:
        print(link.getAttribute("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below XPATH to find element

```
//For 'Upcoming Event' span ..
 XPATH = "//span//b[text()='Upcoming Event']//a"
//For 'Recent Free LIVE Webinars' span ...
 XPATH="//span//b[text()='Recent Free LIVE Webinars']//a"
```